# Execute command for all windows in the screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I use screen and sometimes I change my .bashrc profile. Therefore, I want to apply .bashrc changes for all screen windows. Unfortunately, screen reads profile only for creating new window and doesn't reload .bashrc for existing windows.

My screen session has one or more windows. Before attaching screen I want to execute command for each window. The command is simple "source ~/.bashrc".

I try:

```
screen -X stuff "source ~/.bashrc"`echo -ne '\015'`
```

It's worked perfectly only for one window. So I can't iterate through screen windows using "prev" or "next" command.

I already have read screen man, docs, and I event try to search solution of my problem :)

Can you direct me to right direction? Or maybe somebody already solved similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a recent version of `screen` you can use the `-Q` option, see [original thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-users/2010-02/msg00031.html) and [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/464162/133552). This works here:

```
screen -Q windows | sed 's/[^0-9]*/\n/g; s/^\n//g' \
| while read; do 
    screen -S test -p $REPLY -X stuff "source ~/.bashrc"$'\n'
  done
```

With:

```
$ screen --version
Screen version 4.01.00devel (GNU) 2-May-06
```

Note, if you have multiple session, name them with `-S`. In this case I'm working with a session called `test`. `-p` tells screen which window to send the command to.

Note also the use of [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) (`$'\n'`).

When the `-Q` command executes, `screen` waits `msgwait` seconds before running the commands, work around this by setting `msgwait` to zero and reset it after execution i.e.

```
screen -S test -X msgwait 0
...
screen -S test -X msgwait 5
```

5 is the default value.

Comment: Thx! My screen version is 4.00.03jw4. I dunno screen name because I use `screen -RR` (see [Automatically start SCREEN on SSH login](http://pascal.nextrem.ch/2010/04/30/automatically-start-screen-on-ssh-login/)). However, I have no more then one screen session. I'll try to use new version of screen and your solution. Maybe it saves the day :)